# How to null struct when passed to function?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, struct, null

I want to NULL the head structure in case the head->next is NULL.
However it doesn't work when I pass it into a function to null it.

```
void remove(struct node* head)
{
 int val;

 cout << "Enter a value to delete: ";
 cin >> val;

 if (head->next == NULL)
  if (head->data == val)
   head = NULL;
}
```

Though it works fine when not passed to the function, but done directly in the main function.
Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the pointer which lets you modify the `node` it points to, but you can't modify the pointer itself because the pointer itself is passed by value. So you can't do this in your `remove` function:

```
node = NULL;
```

A solution that people have given you is to pass it as a reference to the pointer, as in `node *&head` and this works perfectly fine. However I believe you'd like to know that the general convention for this sort of thing (modifying a pointer itself) is by passing a double pointer (i.e. a pointer to the pointer to `node`):

```
void remove(node **head) { ... }
```

Then in main you pass it the address of the pointer:

```
node *theHead = blah;
remove(&theHead);
```

Then in `remove` you can change the value of the pointer:

```
*head = NULL;
```

And you can also dereference it of course:

```
(*head)->next; // etc
```

Comment: Ahh okay. 

One question then.
node *theHead = NULL;
remove(theHead);

node *theHead = NULL;
remove(&theHead);

Wouldn't the first one be passed by reference instead of value?
The first one is a pointer to an address
While the other dereference it.

Or I got this wrong?

Comment: @user2180833 Nah. In the first case, you are passing the pointer by value (but of course `remove` can dereference the pointer and modify that value; but you can't modify the pointer itself like setting it to NULL). In the second, you're passing it the address of the pointer. Think of it like going meta, one level higher. One source of confusion is that in this case, `&theHead` _does not_ mean pass by reference. The `&` in this context is the address-of operator, which you use to initialize pointers.

Comment: @user2180833 The context in which `&` means pass-by-reference is in parameters for functions, e.g. if it were `void remove(node &head)` then if you passed a `node` value to `remove` like this: `node someValue = whatever; remove(someValue);` then it would pass by reference.

Comment: @user2180833 You're welcome, I'm glad I could help clear that up. It can indeed be tricky, I think mainly due to the different uses of the `&` operator in different context (at least it was my source of confusion with pointers when I was learning).

Answer (score 4):

The pointer passed as an argument to `remove` is being copied into the function. The `head` inside the function is a copy of that pointer. You set that copy to `NULL` and the one outside is left unchanged. You can simply take the pointer by reference:

```
void remove(struct node*& head)
{
  // ...
}
```

Note the ampersand in the type of `head`. This means it's a "reference to pointer to `node`" and lets you reference precisely the object that is passed, rather than a copy of it.

Comment: Not a copy. I already give the addres:
main
{
struct node *head = NULL;
remove(head);
}

Comment: @user2180833 Yes, that call to `remove` will copy the value of the `head` pointer into the function. C++ uses pass-by-value semantics unless you explicitly ask for a reference.